# ImageView fails to load shortened url, only sometimes

Tags: java, javafx

I've observed a weird behavior (bug?) while loading images with `ImageView` providing a *shortened* link but won't happen with every image. I've tried other shortened images with success.

Here's an MVCE that just loads a blank white window. The target url is:

[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/kindle/merch/2017/ECHO/GW/D_GW_BLU_2UP_1500x300.*CB536733694*.jpg](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/kindle/merch/2017/ECHO/GW/D_GW_BLU_2UP_1500x300._CB536733694_.jpg)

Which *does* load.

```
public class ImageTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ImageView v = new ImageView("http://bit. ly/2liTJCa");

        Scene s = new Scene(new StackPane(v));
        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Note I've broken up the bitly link, since SO won't allow me to post it otherwise, just remove that extra space when testing.

---

**EDIT:** I managed to see an exception by calling `img.getException()` to the underlying `Image` object:

```
com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageStorageException: No loader for image data
```

Comment: I believe this has something to do with the redirection of the shortened link, as ImageView will not follow a redirect as it is expecting an Image not another link. My only other thinking is that it may be due to the dot after the size 1500x300.CB536733694.jpg is there anyway you can get rid of this extra dot?

Comment: sorry I only just read the part about the first link 'does load' ignore the second part

Comment: @TravisF I tried other shortened links and it did work. Also thought of your idea but this just stumped me. Btw i fear it's a network issue with my router, can you please try it on your machine?

Comment: I will in a sec, in the mean time, are you able to visit the link separately (i mean outside of JavaFX like in a browser) if you can then your router would be letting it through.

Comment: alright so I tested it with the bitly link and it didn't work, I then tested it with the link at the top.... again it didn't work, but interestingly the link at the top and the link that it ends up are different, when I changed the link to the physical link it ends up at being `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/kindle/merch/2017/ECHO/GW/D_GW_BLU_2UP_1500x300._CB536733694_.jpg` it does work, are you able to check your endpoint link that your bitly is going to?

Comment: @TravisF Wow didn't notice these underscores but it clearly worked for me as is. Unfortunately i'm out of my office now, can't check.

Comment: @TravisF If i recall, the link in the post is where bitly is set to forward. So i think we have a solution that has nothing with shortening. The `ImageView` redirect mechanism will not function if the link itself has a proper file extension. Makes sense? My browser loads it correctly no matter which of these 3 links i use.

Comment: hopefully, let me know how you go when you get a chance to test it.

Comment: @TravisF Please look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw7jk.png) snapshot. As you can see It clearly points to the physical link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135908/discussion-between-travisf-and-mouseevent).